# Flutter Vertical Tabs only scrolls in horizontal direction

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

i used  vertical_tabs: ^0.2.0 package on flutter 2.0.2 and running on an android virtual device. but the vertical tabs only scrolls horizontally. i copied the exact code from the demo
[Flutter Vertical_tabs](https://pub.dev/packages/vertical_tabs/example). can't find whats wrong.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:vertical_tabs/vertical_tabs.dart';

    void main() {
      runApp(Home());
    }

    class Home extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
    }

    class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: VerticalTabs(
            tabs: <Tab>[
              Tab(child: Text('Flutter'), icon: Icon(Icons.phone)),
              Tab(child: Text('Dart')),
              Tab(child: Text('NodeJS')),
              Tab(child: Text('PHP')),
              Tab(child: Text('HTML 5')),
            ],
            contents: <Widget>[
              Container(child: Text('Flutter'), padding: EdgeInsets.all(20)),
              Container(child: Text('Dart'), padding: EdgeInsets.all(20)),
              Container(child: Text('NodeJS'), padding: EdgeInsets.all(20)),
              Container(child: Text('PHP'), padding: EdgeInsets.all(20)),
              Container(child: Text('HTML 5'), padding: EdgeInsets.all(20))
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: By Tabs scrolled vertically, do you mean the animation transition on selecting a new tab is scrolling horizontally, but you would like the `TabBar` as well as the Animation to scroll vertically?

Comment: this code right here should scroll vertically (documentation). but scrolls horizontally. Not the animation transition.

Answer (score 3):

The [VerticalTab](https://pub.dev/documentation/vertical_tabs/latest/vertical_tabs/VerticalTabs-class.html) widget has two possible content scroll directions: vertical and horizontal. Even though the widget is called VerticalTab, the scroll axis defaults to horizontal. The fix is easy, set the `contentScrollAxis` to `Axis.vertical`, like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return VerticalTabs(
    contentScrollAxis: Axis.vertical,
    tabs: <Tab>[
      // Your tabs
    ],
    contents: <Widget>[
      // Your content
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: I will try this. but by this do you mean they have an error in the documentation?

Comment: No, I meant that it might be a little bit unintuitive, because of the naming. :D

Answer (score 0):

here,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vertical_tabs/vertical_tabs.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Home());
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: VerticalTabs(
        contentScrollAxis: Axis.vertical,
        tabs: <Tab>[
          Tab(child: Text('Flutter'), icon: Icon(Icons.phone)),
          Tab(child: Text('Dart')),
          Tab(child: Text('NodeJS')),
          Tab(child: Text('PHP')),
          Tab(child: Text('HTML 5')),
        ],
        contents: <Widget>[
          Container(child: Text('Flutter'), padding: EdgeInsets.all(20)),
          Container(child: Text('Dart'), padding: EdgeInsets.all(20)),
          Container(child: Text('NodeJS'), padding: EdgeInsets.all(20)),
          Container(child: Text('PHP'), padding: EdgeInsets.all(20)),
          Container(child: Text('HTML 5'), padding: EdgeInsets.all(20))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sharing code just didn't help until unless a description is provided.